# Epsilon-delta definition of continuity for the function (x,y)$\mapsto\frac{x}{y}$

Tags: analysis, continuity

I have to proof that

f: {(x,y)$\in\mathbb{R}^2$|y$\neq$0}$\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

(x,y)$\mapsto \frac{x}{y}$

is continuous.

So I try to estimate:
$|\frac{x}{y}-\frac{x_0}{y_0}|$=$|\frac{xy_0-x_0y}{yy_0}|$=$|\frac{xy_0-x_0y_0+x_0y_0-x_0y}{yy_0}|$=$|\frac{(x-x_0)y_0+x_0(y_0-y)}{yy_0}| \leq |\frac{(x-x_0)y_0}{yy_0}|+|\frac{(y_0-y)x_0}{yy_0}|$

Now how do I choose $\delta$?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What if you first prove that $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ is continuous ?

Comment: Use the theorem about quotients of continuous functions, or mimic its $\epsilon-\delta$ proof.

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate...

Comment: Where can I find?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_n,y_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R^2$ with limit $(x,y)$, such that $y\ne 0$ and $y_n\ne 0$ for all $n$. Let $a:=\sup_n |x_n|$ and $b:=\sup_n |y_n|$. Then
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x_n}{y_n}-\frac xy\right|& = \left|\frac{x_ny-y_nx}{y_ny} \right|\\&= \left|\frac{x_n(y-y_n)-y_n(x-x_n)}{y_ny} \right|\\
&\leqslant \left|\frac{x_n(y-y_n)}{y_ny} \right|+\left|\frac{y_n(x-x_n)}{y_ny} \right|\\
&\left|\frac1y \right| \left|\frac ab|y-y_n|+\left|x-x_n\right|\right|.
\end{align}
Since $(x_n,y_n)\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow(x,y)$, $x_n\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow x$ and $y_n\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow y$, we may choose $N$ such that for $n\geqslant N$,
$$
|x-x_n|< \frac {|y|\varepsilon}{2}, \ |y-y_n|< \frac{b|y|\varepsilon}{2a},
$$
so that
$$
\left|\frac{x_n}{y_n}-\frac xy\right| < \varepsilon
$$
for all but finitely many $n$, as desired.